# Android: get description of an app

Tags: android, package

I want to get the user to install a non-market android app. When he clicks the app icon, i want to show him a page describing the app. Is there any way to get the app's description from its package?

**EDIT:**
I will clarify my question: In The AndroidManifest.xml, there is a "Description" field under the Application window. I am wondering if this field contains a description about the app, and if this description can be accessed in a way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PackageManager.getApplicationInfo()` to get an `ApplicatioInfo` object of the package, and then use `ApplicatioInfo.loadDescription` to get the description.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.package", 0);
appInfo.loadDescription(pm);
```

Answer (score -1):

In "service"
eg

```
<service android:name="different.theme.layer.lwp.template.LiveWallpaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:description="@string/description"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

And in strings add:

```
<string name="description">xxx</string>
```

Pandik.